# debug bar symfony not working

Tags: php, debugging, symfony

The debug bar is not showing at the bottom of the website:

This is my base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="fr">
<head><meta name="google-site-verification" content="8ftgUdHWfZa5ANhU7DJxSpGof4khdKGz5X0phHaWa64" />
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title><meta name="description" content="Location en ligne de vêtements et accessoires de luxe entre particuliers : robes, costumes, sacs, vestes - Assurance incluse - Authenticité 100% garantie."><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('bundles/frontoffice/images/faviconii.png') }}"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ asset('bundles/frontoffice/images/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png') }}"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="{{ asset('bundles/frontoffice/images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png') }}"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="{{ asset('bundles/frontoffice/images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png') }}">
{% block stylesheets  %}  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/generalstyle.css') }}" type="text/css" />
{% endblock %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.smartlook||(function(d) {
    var o=smartlook=function(){ o.api.push(arguments)},h=d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var c=d.createElement('script');o.api=new Array();c.async=true;c.type='text/javascript';
    c.charset='utf-8';c.src='//rec.smartlook.com/recorder.js';h.appendChild(c);
    })(document);
    smartlook('init', 'fec4728dc14b7eb5ae97ba5745a6fcc5763e911c');
</script>



</head>
<body>
{{ render(controller("ADFrontBundle:Default:menu")) }} 
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
{{ include("ADFrontBundle:Default:footer/pied.html.twig") }}
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
      n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
      n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
      t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
        document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
      fbq('init', '1139325582796441');
      fbq('track', "PageView");</script><noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
        src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1139325582796441&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
        /></noscript><script type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
{% block javascript %}
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script><script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/2.2.1/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.1.8/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-smooth-scroll/1.4.10/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-parallax/1.1.3/jquery-parallax-min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.32/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
{%  endblock %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/skrollr.min.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/wow.min.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/page-scroll.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.easypiechart.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.isotope.min.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/popup-gallery.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/text-effect.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.tools.min.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}     
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.revolution.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/counter.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.fitvids.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.geocomplete.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/chosen.jquery.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts '@ADFrontBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.chosen-select').chosen();
$('.chosen-select-deselect').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
$("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
details: "form",
blur: true,
geocodeAfterResult: true
});}); </script>
{% for message in app.session.flashbag.get('facebookNotValid') %}

<div id="my-modal" style="display:block;" class="modal fade in">
    <div  class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top:20%;">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 92%;   margin: 0 auto;">
            <div style="padding: 30px;    border: none;" class="modal-header">
                <span style="text-transform: uppercase;" class="text-center slider-subtitle5 black-text no-margin-bottom">Vérification adresse email</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-facebook modal-body" style="padding: 30px; height: 174px;">
                <p  class="paragraphe-facebook" >Afin de profiter de toutes les fonctionnalités de Dressingavenue.com, veuillez renseigner une adresse email valide</p>
                <div class="email-facebook col-sm-12" style="display: block;">
                      <form method="POST" action="{{   path('valider_fb') }}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}" / >

                          <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8 no-padding"><input type="text" name="emailFb" placeholder="Votre E-mail ..." style="text-transform:lowercase;padding: 9px;" required="" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}$"></div>

                           <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4  col-xs-4 no-padding"><button type="submit" class="highlight-button btn btn-medium button  no-margin bg-logo2 white-text no-border">Valider</button></div>
                      </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>

{% endfor %}
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

var close=true;
$('.display-it').click(function(){
    $('.panel-mobile-hide').slideToggle( "slow" ,function(){
      if(close){
          $('.display-it').removeClass( "fa-minus" );
          $('.display-it').addClass( "fa-plus" );
          close=false;
      }else{
         $('.display-it').removeClass( "fa-plus" );
          $('.display-it').addClass( "fa-minus" );
          close=true;
      }
    });
});

    if($('#fos_user_registration_form_tel').length){
   $('#fos_user_registration_form_tel').prop("type", "tel");
}

    if($('.telephone-input').length){
   $('.telephone-input').prop("type", "tel");
}
});
</script>

<script src='https://cdn.slaask.com/chat.js'></script>
<script>
    _slaask.init('74cfba4484b889bb6949aec78237743f');
</script>

<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-79582949-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}

<script>
  smartlook('tag', 'email', '{{ app.user.email }}');
  smartlook('tag', 'name', '{{ app.user.prenom|title }} {{ app.user.nom|title }} ');
</script>
{% endif %}

</body></html>
```

This my app kernel:

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    $bundles[] = new CoreSphere\ConsoleBundle\CoreSphereConsoleBundle();
}
```

This is my app_dev.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
// for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '41.250.108.226','fe80::1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

/**
 * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Welcome, please edit your post, add your layout and template so we have more clue to find the problem. Are you using the /app_dev.php controller ?

Comment: which environment you are working on?

Comment: i work with symfony 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `</body>` on your view.
So just put an html structure, it will work

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: His original post does have a html closing tag. Feel free to close your answer.

Comment: yes, he has edit after, but how i close ? i'm new here ^^

Answer (score 1):

There may be more than one possible reasons behind this issue.

**Reason #1**

Debug mode is enabled by default in development environment and if you want to enable it you have to put below statement in `app.php` placed in **web** folder.

```
Debug::enable();
```

> If you are using custom created environment than add `Debug::enable();` in `<Env Name>.php` in web folder

**Reason #2**

If you are using development environment than make sure that `Debug::enable();` is already there in `app_dev.php` file.

**Update #1**

Also, Pls check any JavaScript errors occur or not while loading page from browser's console

Comment: Or just use the internal PHP Server by php app/console server:start and then localhost:8000. (For Symfony 2). So the default enviroment is dev

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing your route via appending `app_dev.php` to the URL? If so, make sure in this line:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '41.250.108.226','fe80::1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
)
```

That in the array `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, it contains the IP address of the host that you want to use to access your server. I presume you've edited it and added `41.250.108.226`.

If all that is good, then you can access the debug environment and route via the debug URL. Let's say for example you wanted to access the server via your localhost, then to see the debug bar using debug URL, you would enter this in a browser:

http://localhost/app_dev.php

Let us know if that works. If not, then you may have changed something in your environment.

Comment: i think i nedd to change somting in my environment

Comment: Hi, can you go into `var/logs` and clear out the `dev.log` file and then reload the debug URL, then check the `dev.log` file to see what it shows?

Comment: Looks like the Swiftmailer is sending an email `"Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate"`. I wonder if you are trying to [intercept that and debug](http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/dev_environment.html#viewing-from-the-web-debug-toolbar)? I've done this before and when it happens you may not see the debug bar. Can you maybe check this and disable the code to troubleshoot?